# The question is from the chapter matrix.

Tags: matrices, determinant

The question was asked in my class of matrix and determinants.

Suppose for two matrices A and B, we have trace(AB) = trace(A)trace(B). Then trace(A²-B²) = ?
a)[trace(AB)]²
b)trace(AB²A)
c)trace(AB)²
d)trace(BABA)

All I could do is reach till..
trace(A²-B²) = trace(A-B)(A+B) , A²-B² = (A+B)(A-B).
or, trace(A-B)trace(A+B)
after some manipulations trace²A - trace²B
But not further.
Can someone please help.

Comment: What is the difference between (a) and (c)?

Comment: The title suggests 'determinant' but the body of the question uses trace and no determinant. Please fix it.

Comment: Done. Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 1):

With $A=[1]$, $B=[1]$ the answer is "none of the above".

Comment: Sorry but that isn't an option.

Comment: I'm afraid it is the only option - if you have copied the question correctly.